# Using value classes in scala to implement trait methods?

Tags: scala, implicit

I have a trait that defines a function--I don't want to specify how it will work until later.  This trait is mixed in with several case classes, like so:

```
trait AnItem
trait DataFormatable {
  def render():String = "" // dummy implementation
}
case class Person(name:String, age:Int) extends DataFormatable with AnItem
case class Building(numFloors:Int) extends DataFormatable with AnItem
```

Ok, so now I want includable modules that pimp specific implementations of this render behavior.  Trying to use value classes here:

```
object JSON {
  implicit class PersonRender( val p:Person ) extends AnyVal {
    def render():String = {
      //render json
    }
  }
  // others
}

object XML {
  implicit class PersonRender( val p:Person ) extends AnyVal {
    def render():String = {
      //render xml
    }
  }
  // others
}
```

The ideal use would look like this (presuming JSON output desired):

```
import JSON._
val p:AnItem = Person("John",24)
println(p.render())
```

All cool--but it doesn't work.  Is there a way I can make this loadable-implementation thing work?  Am I close?

Answer (score 0):

The `DataFormatable` trait is doing nothing here but holding you back. You should just get rid of it. Since you want to swap out `render` implementations based on the existence of implicits in scope, `Person` *can't* have it's own `render` method. The compiler will only look for an implicit conversion to `PersonRender` if `Person` doesn't have a method named `render` in the first place. But because `Person` inherits (or is forced to implement) `render` from `DataFormatable`, there is no need to look for the implicit conversion.

Based on your edit, if you have a collection of `List[AnItem]`, it is also not possible to implicitly convert the elements to have `render`. While each of the sub-classes may have an implicit conversion that gives them `render`, the compiler doesn't know that when they are all piled into a list of a more abstract type. Particularly an empty trait such as `AnItem`.

How can you make this work? You have two simple options.

One, if you want to stick with the implicit conversions, you need to remove `DataFormatable` as the super-type of your case classes, so that they do not have their own `render` method. Then you can swap out `XML._` and `JSON._`, and the conversions should work. However, you won't be allowed mixed collections.

Two, drop the implicits altogether and have your trait look like this:

```
trait DataFormatable {
    def toXML: String
    def toJSON: String
}
```

This way, you force every class that mixes in `DataFormatable` to contain serialization information (which is the way it should be, rather than hiding them in implicits). Now, when you have a `List[DataFormatable]`, you can prove all of the elements can both be converted to JSON or XML, so you can convert a mixed list. I think this would be much better overall, as the code should be more straightforward. What imports you have shouldn't really be defining the behavior of what follows. Imagine the confusion that can arise because `XML._` has been imported at the top of the file instead of `JSON._`.

Comment: I think I get that.  So I've updated my example.  What if I have a collection of objects (traits) with different implementations (say a list of AnItem above) and I wanted to render them as JSON or XML depending.  If none of them implement render() then, operating on the trait (AnItem) in the modded example, how would the compiler find a render()?

Comment: It can't based on the type information of `AnItem`. Either the compiler needs to know you have `Person` so it can find the right implicit, or `Person` (and other types) perhaps should implement methods such as `toJSON` and `toXML` from a common trait. It depends on which way you want to go.